# NSDateFormatter dateFromString 1981-04-01

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have code:

```
NSString *str = @"1981-04-01";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *back = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog("output: %@", back); //output (null)
```

When i try different dates:

str = @"1982-04-01"; //also return nil

str = @"1985-04-01"; //thats looks good, output: 1985-03-31 20:00:00 +0000

Looks like my timezone is GMT+4.
Testing in simulator: xcode 6.3, ios 8.3 (iphone5s)

Why NSDateFormatter returns sometimes nil?

I believe its something to do with my Region: Estonia.
Images about OSX and iOS region settings.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ignis.ee](http://darx.ignis.ee/osx_language_region.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [ignis.ee](http://darx.ignis.ee/ios_language_region.png))</sub>

**RESOLVED:** must be daylight saving switch issue. Please read behind @Matthias Bauch comments.

2. Adding dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; works great!

Comment: the above code snippet is working perfectly at my end. did u try cleaning the code and resetting the simulator?

Comment: What's your locale? Maybe something significant happened between 1982 and 1985 in your country? That's why setting a locale is not optional if you do string-2-date conversions. `dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];` will probably fix your problems.

Comment: I have tried add locale, but the result still null.
<code>
NSLocale *usLocake = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
</code>

I belive here something to do with my Timezone: Estonia
Added region settings pictures to main post.

Comment: April 1 1981 was [the day](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/estonia/tallinn?year=1981) Estonia switched to daylight saving time. They turned their clocks from 00:00 to 01:00. Strictly speaking that means there is no "April 1 1981 00:00". But NSDateFormatter should actually handle this correctly and simply return `April 1 1981 01:00`

Comment: This is a much-asked question.  Please search.  You cannot use `NSLog()` to view `NSDate` objects as the dates are printed in GMT timezone.  Use `NSDateFormatter` to format the string.

Comment: @trojanfoe have you actually read the question?

Comment: @Sulthan Yup.  It's like 30+ others on this site.

Comment: Ah OK - I see.  Never mind.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490235/nsdateformatter-cant-parse-1988-04-10-to-nsdate-instance-in-ios-6-is-it-a-b/15490325#15490325

Comment: And in 1985 Estonia switched to the european standard of changing clocks from 2:00 to 3:00. It's pretty much guaranteed that this is a daylight saving switch issue.

Comment: Thank you @Matthias Bauch - i think right answer is date 1981-04-01 00:00:00 don't exists because of Estonia switched to daylight saving time.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to just set up the time zone to GMT like

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
```

The full code from your view like. .

```
NSString *str = @"1981-04-01";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *back = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];

NSLog(@"output: %@", back);
```

Your output like

```
output: 1981-04-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: You can try out this, and if you have any query, plz update on it.